# How exactly does the Maxwell Stress Tensor sniff out what is going on inside a surface?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, charge, maxwell-equations

While studying about the Maxwell Stress Tensor from Griffiths Chapter 8 Conservation laws, I faced this problem.

First of all, he calculated the force on a volume $\mathcal V$ containing a charge distribution $\rho$ and current density $\vec J$(which were assumed to be finite, since that is the only way IMO you can neglect the fields of infinitesimal volumes when calculating forces on them).

So far so good,the answer came out to be-

$$\vec F= \int_{\mathcal V} \nabla \cdot \overleftrightarrow{T}\ d\tau - \dfrac{d}{dt} \epsilon_o\mu_o\ \int_\mathcal V \ \vec S\ d\tau =  \oint_{\mathcal S} \overleftrightarrow{T} \cdot \vec{da} - \dfrac{d}{dt} \epsilon_o\mu_o\ \int_\mathcal V \ \vec S\ d\tau $$

After that, Griffiths makes the claim that integrating over the volume $\mathcal V$ is not necessary, you can take any volume that encloses the whole charge. This claim is obvious, since no charges or currents means no force at those points.

Now, the problem: Let us take two point charges and calculate the Coulombic force between them, using this approach. Consider one charge enclosed within a hemisphere of infinite radius, and you can integrate the stress tensor along the infinite plane between them, the answer comes out to be $q^2/4\pi \epsilon_o r^2$, as expected.

But if the derivation is for finite charge densities, why does an infinite charge density at the location of a charge not ruin the results? My guess is that it is the artistry of converting the volumetric integral into a surface one, which as Griffiths says- *sniffs* out what is going on inside.

I think that it gets clear precisely because $\int d^3r\delta^3(\vec r) =1$, and this finite integral is subtly involved somewhere which hides the presence of singular charges inside the volume.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Not quite clear where your confusion lies. Are you asking why Gauss' theorem is true? That's the only way you will turn a volume integral into a surface integral. No "artistry" to be found.

Comment: Gauss theorem is true I say. But I want to ask why do singular charges not cause a problem while calculating forces on them?

Comment: I am now more unclear on your problem. Is your issue with how the surface integral version picks up the charge, or the volume integral version.

Comment: My issue is this- Why does the stress tensor approach work with  singular charges, even when the derivation is for finite charge densities.

Comment: @Richard Myers, I edited it.

Answer (score 1):

For a point-charged particle, the problem of the 'infinite' charge density can be solved by expressing the charge density as the product of its electrical charge and Dirac's delta distribution function. According to your reasoning, then Gauss's law must also fail for point-charged particle since the right hand side of it will be infinite. By using Dirac's distribution function, all these could be solved mathematically. Physically speaking, the reason why the derivation that Griffiths presented applies to point-charged particle is the same as why the Gauss's law should apply to point particle becuase in the case of singular particle, we just need to insert the Dirac's distribution function into $eq.(8.15)$ and you will get Lorentz force law for point-charged particle. Besdies, during the derivation, no extra physical information except the Maxwell's equations which, as we know, applies to point-charged particle is invoked and the insertion of some mathematical identities should not affect the validness of the result altogether.